# What are some common examples of Homeoteleuton?

Tags: meaning, phrases, poetic

A Google search reveals only a handful or arcane examples. Maybe the brilliant minds here have some ideas.

From the Wikipedia [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeoteleuton):

> As rhyme, homeoteleuton is not very effective. It is the repetition of
>   word endings. Because endings are usually unstressed and rhyme arises
>   from stressed syllables, they do not rhyme well at all.

For example from TV:
"Bounty: the quicker picker upper"

But what other more contemporary examples can you think of?

Thanks!

Comment: That article has more examples, doesn't it? I don't have any on hand because I just learned the word now.

Comment: There are a number of examples, new and not new, at this site: http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/homoioterms.htm

Comment: Nice word. A shame many of the examples in the link include rhyme and assonance, making homoioteleuton itself harder to appreciate.

Comment: I remember the slogan of a UK advertisement campaign for milk whose motto was [Drinka pinta milka day](http://images.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vectis.co.uk%2FAuctionImages%2F469%2F1382_l.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vectis.co.uk%2FPage%2FViewAuctionLots.aspx%3FAuctionId%3D469%26DayNo%3D2%26Section%3D3409%26Start%3D40&h=522&w=1000&tbnid=7YtUvGXRla1ISM%3A&docid=5H_mX1k842e5eM&hl=fr&ei=wb-gVruREMf6aqzViKAC&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=4941&page=2&start=33&ndsp=37&ved=0ahUKEwj79cqv5brKAhVHvRoKHawqAiQQrQMI4wEwPg&biw=1280&bih=902)

Comment: This appears to be a list question. [To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid](/help/dont-ask)

Comment: **Meet and greet** for sociable occasions. **Walk and talk** for ambulatory conversation. **Hop and chop** for Kung Fu movies